# Angular Constant Files Exports

Tags: angular

Quick question.  I have a constants TS file where I am defining all my constants such as:

```
export const MY_TEST_CONSTANT = `Something`;
export const MY_TEST_CONSTANT2 = `Something Else`;
```

In the main component I have:

```
import {MY_TEST_CONSTANT, MY_TEST_CONSTANT2 } from './Constants';
```

Is there a way to just be able to add like a import * to be able to use them versus defining everyone in the import?

Thanks

Comment: import * as consts from './Constants'; -> consts.MY_TEST_CONSTANT

Comment: @enno.void 's answer is the legit only valid one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store your constant as an Object like :

```
export const MY_CONSTANTS = {
    'value1' : 'test1',
    'value2' : 'test2'
};
```

you can now import just MY_CONSTANTS in your component and access to you constants value by doing this:

```
MY_CONSTANTS.value1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your './Constants' file as

```
export const myConstants = {
'MY_TEST_CONSTANT': 'Something',
'MY_TEST_CONSTANT2': 'Something else'
};
```

And import your constants like,

```
import { myConstants as someAlias} from './Constants';
```

or just as

```
import { myConstants } from './Constants';
```

and `someAlias.MY_TEST_CONSTANT(if you have used alias)/ myConstants.MY_TEST_CONSTANT` will give you 'Something'.